# How do I go about calculating final temperature of tank draining at saturation?

Tags: gas-laws, pressure, vapor-pressure, ideal-gas

I am working on calculating pressure in a tank where the fluid is sitting at its vapor pressure. For example, imagine a 12 in diameter 100 L tank of nitrous oxide at room temperature (745 psi vapor pressure). This tank would be drained at 1 L/s from the liquid side, and some of the nitrous oxide would boil off in order to maintain vapor pressure, but would come at the cost of reducing the temperature and vapor pressure in the fluid.

How do I find what the final fluid temperature at drain would be (assuming no heat being input into the system)?

I was thinking there would be some combination of Antoine's, Clausius-Clapeyron, ideal gas law, and some derivation of an energy balance equation, but I am not too sure.

The experimental situation would literally be a tank (assume perfect insulation) that is filled with nitrous oxide, say a 100 L tank because it is arbitrary. This tank would then be drained through a choked orifice into the atmosphere. The flowrate at the start would be 1 L/s, but as pressure drops, would decrease in flowrate. I want to find out the ending pressure and temperature when the liquid would run out. Experimental data points to the tank draining from liquid before running out, similar to how a propane barbeque runs out of liquid and becomes cold with lower pressures.

Comment: If you can truly assume an isolated system, then the final temperature would be about -88.5 Deg C (nitrous oxide boiling point), varying with atmospheric pressure. Assume it would be high T and high p scenario for water. Final temp would be 100 Deg C. Similarly for LPG with complication of being a mixture. But in all cases it would be asymptotical final state.

Comment: Unless you mean the lowest temperature still able to supply 1 L/s. Final T would be then the T with pressure able to provide the given flow with the fully open valve. There is not enough data for that.

Comment: I guess my question is what would be the temperature where the fluid runs out? The drain rate would be out of a choked orifice, so upstream pressure would affect the downstream flowrate. We have empirical data that shows ending pressure is around 75% of the starting pressure but want to be able to actually calculate/model this.

Comment: How well insulated the real system is? As with total insulation it would not run out, being in mechanical equilibrium with atmosphere. // I advice to properly describe scenario in the question to prevent task misinterpretation by readers.

Comment: The situation would literally be a tank (assume perfect insulation) that is filled with nitrous oxide, say a 100L tank because it is arbitrary. This tank would then be drained through a choked orifice into the atmosphere. The flowrate at the start would be 1 L/sec, but as pressure drops, would decrease in flowrate. I want to find out the ending pressure and temperature when the liquid would run out. Experimental data points to the tank draining from liquid before running out, similar to how a propane barbeque runs out of liquid and becomes cold with lower pressures.

Comment: If a LPG canister had been isolated, the liquid phase would not have run out as there would have been atmospheric pressure inside. This is observed in similar scenario of limited usability of LPG at low T, even if initially warm.// The deviation from being isolated leads to running out.  // For all cases, the key is to know ratio of the specific or molar liquid heat capacity times T difference and evaporation enthalpy. if low enough, the isolated running out is possible.

Comment: @AlexanderPatrus I was about to answer this question, but something is strange. You state that your tank is in vapor-liquid equilibrium all the time? So, while the pressure of the tank goes down, $ T = T^\pu{sat} $ at the corresponding pressure?

Comment: @MetalStorm Yes that would be the condition in the tank. I am not sure how to calculate the final temperature in order to give me the final pressure. Basically I don't know how to calculate the temperature drop

Comment: @AlexanderPatrus My main concern is that phase transitions for pure fluids (like here with $\ce{N2O}$) take place at constant temperature (or pressure). So, if you have saturated liquid $\ce{N2O}$ and it starts boling at $T^\pu{sat}$, it will keep evaporating until all you have is saturated gas at the same $T^\pu{sat}$ (at least, thermodynamically). Do you have some data?

Comment: @MetalStorm As the tank is isolated, the liquid N2O had to cool down to compensate evaporation enthalpy. It is similar as when one CH SE user was surprised that his chlorine containers were covered by ice. He was assuming it is due adiabatic cooling. He was not aware chlorine is provided liquefied and it was due evaporation enthalpy.

Comment: @Poutnik Hello Poutnik, thanks for the comment. But the tank is not isolated, there is draning. Do you think a process is possible such that, as time passes by, there is always a VLE equilibrium between phases? The mental image would be that of a guy walking the P-T curve, from right to left, along the gas-liquid equilibrium curve.

Comment: @MetalStorm By isolated, I have meant insulated  *(assume perfect insulation)* I do agree by an isolated system is meant an insulated *closed* system. Sorry for confusion. (Czech language uses the same term for both, easy to confuse it.)

Comment: Since the tank would be drained from the liquid portion, the ending pressure would certainly not be atmospheric, it would be something higher. With ending defined as liquid running out.

Comment: For calculations near critical point, evaporation enthalpy, specific liquid and gas heat capacities, gas and liquid densities and adiabatic expansion quite strongly depend on p and T. I am not sure data are available. I am afraid the easier way may be empirical evaluation if applicable.

Answer (score 1):

Let m be the mass of N2O in the tank at any time, x be the mass fraction liquid N2O,V be the tank volume, v be saturated volume per unit mass, u be saturated internal energy per unit mass, and h be saturated enthalpy per unit mass.  At any time, the internal energy of the tank contents will be:  $$U=m[xu_L(T)+(1-x)u_V(T)]$$If we apply the open system version of the 1st law of thermodynamics to the contents of this adiabatically insulated tank, we obtain:  $$dU=h_L(T)dm$$or$$[xu_L(T)+(1-x)u_V(T)]dm-m(u_V-u_L)dx+m\left[x\frac{du_L}{dT}+(1-x)\frac{du_V}{dT}\right]dT=(u_L+Pv_L)dm$$or
$$-(u_V-u_L)dx+\left[x\frac{du_L}{dT}+(1-x)\frac{du_V}{dT}\right]dT=-(1-x)(u_V-u_L)d\ln{m}+Pv_Ld\ln{m}$$This equation is subject to the constraint that the total volume is constant:  $$m[xv_L+(1-x)v_V]=V$$or$$x=\frac{v_V-\frac{V}{m}}{v_V-v_L}$$These equations provide the basis for determining x(m) and T(m).